# error while running a report in OBIEE -> [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred

Tags: obiee

I'm getting below error while running a report in OBIEE(Oracle Business Intelligence tool). Can Anyone give me solution how to solve?

```
Error Codes: YQCO4T56:OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
Location: saw.views.evc.activate, saw.httpserver.processrequest, saw.rpc.server.responder, saw.rpc.server, saw.rpc.server.handleConnection, saw.rpc.server.dispatch, saw.threadpool.socketrpcserver, saw.threads
Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 27002. [nQSError: 27002] Near <interval>: Syntax error (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 26012. [nQSError: 26012] . (HY000)
SQL Issued: {call NQSGetLevelDrillability('SELECT cast(year("Call Date"."Call Date") as char(4)) || right(''0'' || cast (month("Call Date"."Call Date") as varchar(2)), 2) saw_0, "My Operator"."My PMN (TADIG) Code" saw_1 FROM "GSM Analysis Roaming Outbound (Home)" WHERE "Call Date"."Call Date" BETWEEN TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY, -(DayOfMonth(Current_Date)), TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -12, Current_Date)) + interval 1 day AND TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY,-(DayOfMonth(Current_Date)), TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -0, Current_Date))')}
```

Comment: Can any one help how to solve this error plz.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in all the godawful formulas that are going on in that analysis (*not* "report"! but "analysis"). You will have to break the analysis down column by column and just find the calculation that producing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you try refreshing and see if this issue autoresolves itself. It appears that it is also common when session is idle.